# Is it possible to do a scatter plot in Power BI on unsummarized data with a Date as a play axis?

Tags: powerbi

I have the following data in a flat table with unsummarized data.

Each row in the flat table describes a unique data value collected for a given date and hour of the day.

I would like to do a scatter chart where:

- The x-axis is the hour of the day.
- The y-axis is the measured value.
- The Play-axis is the date.

A snippet of actual data is shown below.

[image: Unsummarized data for a scatter chart.]

I can get a basic dot plot using the Power BI over all days by setting the scatter chart X and Y to the unsummarized fields.

*I can probably create hourly box plots from this data by adding an R visualization.*

However, I would like to use the `Play Date` column as the Play axis and animate the measured hourly values over the date range.

[image]

When I add `Play Date` to the visual as the Play Axis, I get the following error:

[image]

> The question is:    How do I create a Measure that, when aggregated,
> returns the field  value for a row?
>
> I have tried a calculated column based on MAX([field],0).  This does
> not work because the aggregate takes the MAX of the entire table.

### My main questions are:

- How would I create a Measure that returns a field value for the current row in my flat table when aggregated on a Power BI scatter chart?
- If I must use a filter, will this adversely affect performance?

### What I have tried so far:

- Tried creating Measures using the DAX SELECTEDVALUE function. For example:

  HourofDay = SELECTEDVALUE(*FlatTable*[X])

  HourlyMeasure = SELECTEDVALUE(*FlatTable*[Y])

This does not work and results in an empty visualization.

- Tried creating a Measure based on the DAX LOOKUPVALUE function.

  ```
  HourofDay = LOOKUPVALUE(rptHourlyNoiseMetrics[X],rptHourlyNoiseMetrics[ID],rptHourlyNoiseMetrics[ID])
  ```

  This throws a error on the third parameter:

  ```
   Cannot find name [ID].
  ```
- I am looking at an R approach. Hopefully, Power BI will not try to send aggegated data into R. Raw data is *really* important.

Comment: Is the date a string or a date?

Comment: You can create measures that select the max value for each column. The visual will understand that when you want to scatter on each day and hour, that it should create a max value for each date-hour combo.

Comment: The Date is a date.

Comment: Hey Doug, I've tried answering your question. I am however not entirely sure if it is what you are looking for, but I have a hard time understanding the exact goal of what you are trying to achieve. Let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the scatter plot without aggregating values is no problem as long as you won't be using the play date. This has to do with the fact that it can not handle multiple values for the same date(time, since you use hours).

The following solution might help you, even though it will aggregate both your X and Y values.

Steps:

- Create two measures: MaxX and MaxY. These measures contain the MAX(table[x/y]).
- In your scatter chart, place MaxX as X-axis and the MaxY as Y-Axis.
- Place Play Date as play date.
- Place X (Non aggregated) into the 'detail' part. (Above legend) This will make your chart work again.

A snippet from my try (I have used some quickly typed data since you didn't include test date in a table):

[image: Scatter plot with play date]

As a last note. Maybe you will have multiple values for each date & hour. You might want to keep this into account when creating the measure for Y and use a SUM instead. Or, if you will have more categories, you could always use the legend function in the future.